# php using result from previous query in another query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to grab a result from one query and pop it into another.

**first query**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM singleprop.jos_mls WHERE MSTMLSNO = ' . $mlsnum . ';';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

**second query**

```
$aquery = 'SELECT * FROM singleprop.jos_agents WHERE AGTBRDIDMM = ' . $row[0] . ';';
$aresult = mysql_query($aquery);
$agent = mysql_fetch_row($aresult);
```

I know about `JOIN`, but don't know how to apply it with a 3rd table.  Does my model have something to do with `$this->`?

Comment: mysql_* function have been deprecated in PHP. Please update your code to use either mysqli_* of pdo_mysql [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: On a side note, it is suggested that you stop using `mysql_*` and start using `PDO` - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php as the former is being deprecated.

Comment: On a further side note, you can just probably use a `JOIN`. Posting schemas helps

Comment: I changed everything over to `mysqli` and everything stopped working.  ...so that sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks good. You could write a query using join, which you are aware of. What is the question?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   singleprop.jos_mls as mls JOIN singleprop.jos_agents 
          ON singleprop.jos_mls.KEY = singleprop.jos_agents.KEY
WHERE mls.MSTMLSNO = $mlsnum
```

where KEY is the join key

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM   singleprop.jos_agents 
WHERE  AGTBRDIDMM = (
                     SELECT COL_NAME 
                     FROM   singleprop.jos_mls 
                     WHERE MSTMLSNO = ' . $mlsnum . '
                    )
```

where `COL_NAME` is the column name for `AGTBRDIDMM` in the first table

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is, I run a 3rd and 4th table and I don't know how to JOIN those in.

I need the second query to contain a value from the first query.  I just don't know how to get it there.

Comment: take a different variable other than query for each query..!

Comment: The code that you originally posted, you yourself included a result from the first query in the second query. That is correct. As I asked in my answer, having done that, what is your question. You seem to be in the right track.

Comment: I'm not getting a result from the second query. If I'm on the right track, I guess I have to comb through my syntax and see if something's out of place.  But I do't have to do something like `$this->$row[0];`, do I? (I tried that and it didn't work)

Comment: Missing quotes on string declaration.